# cordova qr-scanner scan does not show the camera

Tags: cordova, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use cordova qrscanner plugin from:
https://github.com/pubudu-ranasinghe/cordova-plugin-qrscanner2
but scan function **does not show the camera.**

I have a button and on click I have below code:

```
QRScanner.show();
QRScanner.scan(function(err, contents){
    if(err){
      if(err.name === 'SCAN_CANCELED') {
        alert('The scan was canceled before a QR code was found.');
      } else {
        alert(err._message);
      }
    }
    alert('Scan returned: ' + contents);
  });
```

I have tried phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner but it cannot recognise my bad quality barcode.

Your help is much appreciated.

Omid

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ionic you need to set the ion-app transparent when you start the cameraview.

```
window.document.querySelector('ion-app').classList.add('transparentBody');
```

**CSS**

```
.transparentBody {
    background: none transparent !important;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PubuduRanasinghe. I am using cordova. I tried hiding my current page and it is now showing the camera view but does not have barcode placeholder.

Comment: What do you mean by barcode placeholder? The plugin does not come with any UI. The entire camera view is scanned.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks. Your answer is correct and solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because the main ion-app tag is not transparent yet. It covers the camera.

Please refer to this [Native QR Scanner Implementation in Ionic 2](https://medium.com/@piashsarker/native-qr-scanner-implementation-in-ionic-6e1ef01335ea).

Quoted from that link.

Step 1: Add below css in your variable.scss file:

```
ion-app.cameraView, ion-app.cameraView ion-content, ion-app.cameraView .nav-decor {
  background: transparent none !important;
}
```

Step 2: Now, you need to add below two methods in your home.ts file.

```
showCamera() {
  (window.document.querySelector('ion-app') as 
HTMLElement).classList.add('cameraView');
}

hideCamera() {
  (window.document.querySelector('ion-app') as 
HTMLElement).classList.remove('cameraView');
}
```

Now, Call showCamer() method in your ionViewWillEnter() lifecycle method. Also don’t forget to call hideCamera() when you are leaving this page. So you need to call hideCamera() in ionViewWillLeave() lifecycle method.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.showCamera();
}
ionViewWillLeave(){
   this.hideCamera(); 
}
```

I tried. It works so well for me.